# contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAtIndexPaths for UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, contextmenu

We know that iOS 13 adds the ContextMenu function to UITableView, we can use the following method to display the context menu of UITableViewCell:

```
- (nullable UIContextMenuConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point
```

But how can we show a menu for multiple selected rows? Like the "Files" app?

Starting with iOS 16, the UICollectionView added this:

```
- (nullable UIContextMenuConfiguration *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
                                              point:(CGPoint)point
```

It's strange that UITableView doesn't have this function, did Apple forget to do it? :)
Is there a way to achieve the same for UITableView ? Or am I missing something?

Is there a way to achieve the same for UITableView?